# F recursive and surjective. Show that it exists g such that g recursive and f * g = I

Tags: logic, computability

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ recursive and surjective. I need to prove that it exists a function g such that the composition of functions f * g = I where g is also recursive.

My idea :
Let $f(0) = n_0 $  & $f(n+1)=h(f(n))$ for some recursive function $h$. Then define $g$ recursively as the inverse function of $f$. Obviously this doesn't work as I end up using the inverse function of $h$.

I also suspect my definition of a recursive function to be not 100% clear.

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "Recursive function" just means "computable function". It does not mean the function has to be defined by recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it makes things more "flexible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $g(x)$ by computing $f(0), f(1), \ldots$ until you reach the (necessarily smallest) $y$ such that $f(y) =x$.

Crucial point: Because $f$ is surjective, this is guaranteed to terminate for every $x$.

Comment: Thanks. Could this result be extended to a function in $ g : \mathbb{{N}^{k}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ ? E.g. for such a function $g$, bijective, can we show that the inverse function $f(n)=(f_1(n),...,f_k(n))$ is also recursive using a similar argument ? $f_i(n)= min n_i (g(n_1,...,n_i,...,n_k)=n)$

Comment: Did you just switch which of $f$ and $g$ was the known and which the unknown function?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. I don't have enough point to edit my comment so yes it should read $f : \mathbb{{N}^{k}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ . and "can we show that the inverse function $g(n)=(g_1(n),...,g_k(n))$ is also recursive with a similar argument ? $g_i(n)=minn_i(f(n_1,...,n_i,...,n_k)=n)$

Comment: @Stu-D-ent, there is a computable bijection between $\mathbb N^k$ and $\mathbb N$, so those objects are interchangeable as far as the existence of computable functions is concerned.